# Смена цвета фона по нажатию на блок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо найти все `div` на странице и добавить каждому слушатель по клику `("click")`. И при клике на `div` происходила смена цвета фона. Подскажите, что не так сделал

```js
let elem1 = document.querySelectorAll('box');

elem1.forEach(function(document) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div><br>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пропустили точку у селектора класса в `querySelectorAll`

```js
let elem1 = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

elem1.forEach(function(document) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor="black"; 
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div><br>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Ох, как же я долго мучался, спасибо)

Comment: А не подскажете, как сделать, что бы при нажатии он возвращал цвет?

Comment: @GlebPristupa да, самый адекватный вариант classList.toggle()

Answer (score 1):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.box')].forEach((s) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.box')].forEach((s) => {
      s.classList.remove('black');
    });
    s.classList.contains('black') ? s.classList.remove('black') : s.classList.add('black');
  });
});
```

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div><br>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```